# security in web sphere process server

Tags: websphere

After applying the global security my applications shows partial start even though my servers are in the started stage.while removing the security the applications are in start stage can any one help me out ...

Answer (score 0):

After enabling global security, you probably will need to manually synchronize each node (using the syncNode command) and restart all WebSphere instances.

Comment: i have synchronized but the problem still persist.